# Проблема с отправкой записи в инстаграмм

Tags: php

При запуске скрипта постинга в инсту начала вылазить ошибка

`{"message": "checkpoint_required", "checkpoint_url": "https://i.instagram.com/challenge/7802983840/XSEye2p3jb/", "lock": true, "status": "fail", "error_type": "checkpoint_challenge_required"}`

после чего зайдя в саму инсту вылазит окно [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как можно решить проблему ? спасибо

Comment: Нажать "Это я". (Если не вы, искать, кто пытается от Вашего имени заходить)

Comment: при каждом запросе это вылазит .

Comment: вот сам скрипт 
https://github.com/LookHin/instagram-photo-video-upload-api

Comment: Так значит сервер заходил в инсту с Китая и эго просто блокировало, если это дедик поставь впн

Comment: Инстаграмм - это одна большая проблема. Удивляться не надо.